# Woocomerce выбор страны доставки по алфавиту

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем доброго дня! Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Woo в форме заказа сделать выпадающий список стран по алфавиту? Сейчас у меня по умолчанию стоит Россия, но при клике на input первой страной стоит Сомали, потом Грузия и тд. В массиве все города идут по порядку. Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Отключаете стандартную сортировку, добавляете свою

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sort_countries', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries','sort_countries' );

function sort_countries( $countries ) {
    asort($countries);
    return $countries;
}
```

Более правильный вариант в виде [плагина](https://github.com/claudiosanches/wc-properly-sort-countries), но для него нужно расширения [intl](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php), если сможете поставить, то используйте его

Comment: Спасибо , буду посмотреть!!